# How to exclude consonants in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a project that receives the user input, saves it in an array, and then checks if the words are vowels or consonants, everything's fine here, however, i can't get the consonant count correctly.

I discovered two things,

First, if i try to count the consonants while checking each character with the vowels, it gives me the double or triple characters.

Second, i don't know how to count only one time each consonant.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ca">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DAW0612-Pràctica 08</title>
    <link href="imatges/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" rel="Shortcut Icon"/>
    <link href="codi/estil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>A l'inrevés</header>
    <br />
    <div id="missatge"></div>
    <h3 id="paraula"></h3>
    <h4 id="caracters"></h4>
    <p id="consonants"></p>
    <p id="vocals"></p>
    <p id="espais"></p>
    <p id="especials"></p>


    <script>

        /************ COMENÇEU AQUÍ EL VOSTRE CODI ***************************************************************/
        //variables


var frase =[10];
var fraseinreves=[10];
var dump;
var vocales=["a","e","i","o","u"];
var espais = 0;
var j=0;
var vocals = 0;
var consonants = 0;
//programa

frase = window.prompt("Dame una frase cualquiera");
lfrase = frase.length;


for (let i = frase.length -1; i >=0; i--){
    //guardamos la frase al reves dentro de la nueva array
    fraseinreves[j]=frase[i];
  //  resultado += frase[i];
    if (frase[i] == " "){
        espais++;
    }
    //incrementamos el contador de la array nueva
    j++;
}
for (let i = 0; i < frase.length; i ++){
    //guardamos los caracteres uno por uno del array a la constante char
    const char = frase[i]; 
        //window.alert(char);
    window.alert(char);
    
    //creamos un loop para recorrer la array que contiene las vocales
    for (let j = 0; j < vocales.length; j++){
        //SI EL CONTENIDO DE CHAR, ES IGUAL A ALGUNA VOCAL (ESTAS SE RECORREN EN EL SEGUNDO LOOP), entonces:
        if(char == vocales[j]){
            window.alert(char);
            vocals++;
        }
        }
            //contador para las consonantes.
        
    }




        /************ NO TOQUEU EL SEGÜENT CODI ***************************************************************/

        document.getElementById("missatge").innerHTML = fraseinreves;
        document.getElementById("paraula").innerHTML = "Paraula o frase original: <span>" + frase + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("caracters").innerHTML = "Nombre de caràcters: " + lfrase;
        document.getElementById("consonants").innerHTML = "Consonants: " + consonants;
        document.getElementById("vocals").innerHTML = "Vocals: " + vocals;
        document.getElementById("espais").innerHTML = "Espais en blanc: " + espais;
        document.getElementById("especials").innerHTML = "Lletres ñ o ç: " + especial;

    </script>
    <noscript>
        El seu navegador no accepta Javascript, si us plau actualitzis a una versió mes moderna.
    </noscript>
    <br />
    <footer>
        2016 Departament d'Informàtica - INS LA PINEDA - BADALONA<span>DAW M06-Desenvolupament Web en Entorn Client</span>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically i don't want to use any function like `includes()` because i want to improve my thinking, and i want to know what i did bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this will check if the char is not a vowel. if the char is not a vowel, but is still a letter (checked with regex), then it will add to the consonants counter. not sure how to do with without regex or at least an array of all consonants, because otherwise you might start counting spaces and periods and the like.

```
//creamos un loop para recorrer la array que contiene las vocales
for (let j = 0; j < vocales.length; j++){
    //SI EL CONTENIDO DE CHAR, ES IGUAL A ALGUNA VOCAL (ESTAS SE RECORREN EN EL SEGUNDO LOOP), entonces:
    let vocalesFound = false;
    if(char == vocales[j]){
        window.alert(char);
        vocals++;
        vocalesFound = true;
    }
    }
        //contador para las consonantes.
    if ( !vocalesFound && char.match( /[A-Za-z]/ ) ) consonants++;
}
```

Comment: You could lowerCase the char to support uppercase consonants.

Comment: @user3252327 yeah, for sure.